# find and copy particular file to the destination folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder (Mapped Network folder) named DDMMYYYY (created everyday automatically), inside the folder I have several files (100+) gets generated everyday. I just need to copy one specific file (DailyVB.22) from that folder to the destination. How can I find that specific file and copy it to the destination. With local Drive I can copy having only one source folder, however in the network drive everyday new folder is getting generated (DDMMYYYY) I tried the below code but it can copy all files but today's files. please help;

```
@echo on
set Location=C:\test
Set Destination=D:\Development\Test\In
Set FileName=DailyVB.*
Set SearchResult=SearchResult.txt
Where /R "%Location%" "%FileName%" > %SearchResult%
For /f "delims=*" %%a in (%SearchResult%) Do (If Not Exist "%Destination%\%%~na" MD "%Destination%\%%~na")
For /f "delims=*" %%b in (%SearchResult%) Do (echo Copy "%%b" "%Destination%\%%~nb" & Copy /-Y "%%b" "%Destination%\%%~nb")
pause
Explorer "%Destination%"
```

Comment: If you're wanting the specifically named file, `DailyVB.22`, why are you searching with a wildcard file mask? Your search string suggests you're looking for file names beginning with the string `DailyVB.` If you cannot be clear about the task specifications it becomes more difficult for members to help you. Is `.22` the file extension, does the file have a known extension or none at all. _Also it makes more sense for the network directories to be named in a sortable order `yyyyMMdd`_.

Comment: .22 is the date, if I receive the new file today it will be .23. There is no specific file extension.

Comment: It makes more sense to me to search for a directory name using todays `ddMMyyyy` format, then invoke a copy command using that as the source path. But without knowing more about your mapped directory structure, I cannot say for sure if that would be more efficient. Can I also ask why you have used the phrase "copy all files but today's files", when your question was initially regarding "copy one specific file".

Comment: @Compo, i need to copy one specific file only (filename mentioned in the code.